# Youtube analytics, retrieve audience_retention_percentage

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to retrieve the `audienceWatchRatio`. When I run it in the API explorer I receive a valid response but no data.

I know that the video that I filter for have views, and I have enabled the `elapsedVideoTimeRatio`.

Is there something else that I am missing that needs to be set for each user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the start date I were using was set to before the the video that I want to query were uploaded. To make it work the start date had to match the publishedAt date.